# Remove leading zeroes but not all zeroes

Tags: regex, perl

How can I remove all the leading zeroes but leave a final zero if the value only contains zeroes?

for example:

```
my $number = "0000";
```

I would like to have:

```
my $number = "0";
```

I tried:

```
$number =~ s/^0*//;
```

but this of course removes all the zeroes in this case.

Answer (score 24):

This should work:

```
$number =~ s/^0*(\d+)$/$1/;

0    -> 0
0000 -> 0
0001 -> 1
```

Edit: turns out that's just a bit too complicated. This should also work:

```
$number =~ s/0*(\d+)/$1/;
```

but I'm not sure which is better, depends on the use case.

Do check out the answer from [Oesor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678455/remove-leading-zeroes-but-not-all-zeroes/5678727#5678727): it's pretty sweet too, no regex involved.

Comment: Well, I guess in the first case you will not get the match unless the EOL is immediately preceeded by the number so probably 2) gives more flexibility, whereas the first can also do the work to check the format of the input.

Answer (score 13):

This doesn't need to be done as a regex.

```
my @nums = qw/ 00000 000 000001 002 00000005 00000064 /;
@nums = map { $_ + 0 } @nums;
```

Comment: I don't think it's a joke, and it actually more directly addresses what may be the unstated underlying problem, canonicalizing the string representation of numbers.

Comment: This worked too...the data I'm working with is in the form of: $data = "0225 0000 030"; I was using split(" ", $data) then a foreach loop to process. Finishing with a join().

Comment: So you want to end up with `225 0 30`?  Why not just do `$data =~ s/\b0+(\d)/$1/g;`?

Comment: No, just a reminder that putting a string through a numerical then string context is going to strip off leading zeros, among other things. It's of course not suited for large numbers due to some of the other stuff that goes on. For example, `perl -E "say q(000000123456789012345678901234567890) + 0"`

Answer (score 9):

```
$number =~ s/^0+(?=\d)//;
```

The positive lookahead ensures there's at least one digit left, and using `+` instead of `*` means the substitution is skipped if there are no leading zeroes.

If you're trying to normalize groups of numbers in a single string, just use `\b` instead of `^`, and do a global substitution:

```
my $data = "0225 0000 030";
$data =~ s/\b0+(?=\d)//g;
```

Comment: ...or `(?<!\d)` if digit groups might be preceded by letters or [connector punctuation](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pc/list.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Some answers are implicitly assuming there are only digits present or that `$number` is in fact a number.  If this is not the case:

```
s/^0+(?=.)//s
```

Or even:

```
substr($number,0,-1) =~ s/^0+//s
```

Comment: What changed with lvalue substr?

Comment: @ikegami: nothing relevant to this case, I was misremembering.  The change was that the length of the lvalue used to stay fixed, so `$n="01"; for (substr($n,0,-1)) { s/^0+//; print }` would print "1" instead of "".

Answer (score 2):

If your `$number` is an integer, another way is to use [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html):

```
for my $number (qw(005 05 5 000 0 500)) {
    printf "%d\n", $number;
}

__END__

5
5
5
0
0
500
```

Edit: As ysth points out, it works for all integers, not just positive integers as I originally stated.

Comment: Not just positive, strips extra zeros from e.g. '-00005' too.

Answer (score 2):

Just add 0 to the string so that it's implicitly converted to a number:

```
my $var = '0000035600000';
$var += 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `sprintf` function in Perl:

```
# Input variables
$valuesA = "0";
$valuesB = "00001";
$valuesC = "000.1";
$valuesD = "00010";

# Format number with zero leading zeroes
# $valuesA = sprintf("%0d", $valuesA);
$valuesA = sprintf("%0g", $valuesA);
$valuesB = sprintf("%0g", $valuesB);
$valuesC = sprintf("%0g", $valuesC);
$valuesD = sprintf("%0g", $valuesD);

# Output variables
print "valuesA: $valuesA\n"; # returns "0"
print "valuesB: $valuesB\n"; # returns "1"
print "valuesC: $valuesC\n"; # returns "0.1"
print "valuesD: $valuesD\n"; # returns "10"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to replace all by one just change to `s/^0+/0/` ?

However, this will replace all leading 0's by one 0 so if you have leading zeros before numbers you will need Mats construct.

Comment: This will reduce `001` to `01`, which I don't think is what the OP wants.

Comment: `"001"` should become `"1"`, not `"01"`

Comment: @JSBangs,ridgerunner,sverre: You are all correct, I should have thought more about he was actually trying to accomplish, but I do not see any of that in the initial statement. I will put my vote on Mat and change * to +.