# Regex to remove leading zeros in R, unless the final (or only) character is zero

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub, stringr

```
gsub("(?<![0-9])0+", "", c("005", "0AB", "000", "0"), perl = TRUE)
#> [1] "5"  "AB" ""   ""
gsub("(^|[^0-9])0+", "\\1", c("005", "0AB", "000", "0"), perl = TRUE)
#> [1] "5"  "AB" ""   ""
```

The regular expression above [is from this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538576/removing-leading-zeros-from-alphanumeric-characters-in-r) explaining how to remove *all* leading zeros from a string in R. As a consequence of this regular expression both "000" and "0" are transformed into "". Instead I want to remove all leading zeros from a string of characters, except for the cases when the final character happens to be zero, or the only character is zero.

```
"005" would become "5"
"0AB" would become "AB"
"000" would become "0"
"0"   would become "0"
```

[This other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678455/remove-leading-zeroes-but-not-all-zeroes) explains how to do what I want, but I don't think I'm getting the syntax quite correct, applying the solution in R. And I don't really understand the distinction between the 1st and 2nd solution below (if they indeed worked).

```
gsub("s/^0*(\d+)$/$1/;", "", c("005", "0AB", "000", "0"), perl = TRUE)  # 1st solution
# Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""s/^0*(\d"
gsub("s/0*(\d+)/$1/;", "", c("005", "0AB", "000", "0"), perl = TRUE)    # 2nd solution
# Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""s/0*(\d"
```

What is the proper regex in R to get what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may remove all zeros from the start of a string but not the last one:

```
sub("^0+(?!$)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Af84T/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `0+` - one or more zeros
- `(?!$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is an end of string position immediately to the right of the current location

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/Is7IF6):

```
x <- c("005", "0AB", "000", "0")
sub("^0+(?!$)", "", x, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "5"  "AB" "0"  "0"
```

Comment: `regex` noob. What's the performance difference (or other preferences) between your pattern and this one `^0*(.+)$` or `^0+(.+)$`?

Comment: @M-- These are different patterns, it is recommended to only compare performance of equivalent regexps. Yours are a bit inefficient as `.` can match `0` and both adjoining patterns are indefinitely quantified, but just a tiny bit.

Answer (score 3):

We can add one more condition with a regex lookaround to check for any non-zero values after one or more zeros (`0+`)

```
sub("(?<![0-9])0+(?=[^0])", "", sub("^0+$", "0", v1), perl = TRUE)
#[1] "5"  "AB" "0"  "0"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("005", "0AB", "000", "0")
```

Comment: I am not `regex` guru in any way but lookarounds are not efficient, are they? Since you have two `sub` you may want to remove all the leading zeros and replace `""` with `0`? ```sub("^$", "0", sub("^0+", "", v1), perl = TRUE)```

Comment: @M--  It wouldn't be that efficient, but I used it to follow the same code as the OP

Answer (score 3):

You could use an alternation to either match all the zeroes in the string in a capturing group or match all the zeroes from the start of the string.

In the replacement use group 1.

```
^0*(0)$|^0+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wj1fMU/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/WHSgdJ)

For example

```
sub("^0*(0)$|^0+", "\\1", c("005", "0AB", "000", "0"))
```

Output

```
[1] "5"  "AB" "0"  "0"
```

Or even better as commented by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew), you could use capture a single 0 in a group and repeat the group itself to capture the last instance of a zero.

```
^(0)+$|^0+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jbkY14/1/)

Comment: I'd use `^(0)+$|^0+`

Comment: Looks like `sub("^0+(?!$)", "", x, perl=TRUE)` will also work

Answer (score 3):

By using a ***non*** [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\B`. See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fFjbFj/1) or an [R demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##K/r/v1jBRlchWUPJwMBUSUdBycDRCUwZGIApJU2u4tIkDaU4A@2YGLAMEBdrcnH9/w8A).

```
sub("^0+\\B", "", s)
```

This will not match the last zero, because right of it there is no [word character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).

Answer (score 2):

Another `regex` option:

```regex
^0*(.+)$
```

Here's a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uca8yB/3).

Using `base::sub` in R:

```r
sub("^0*(.+)$", "\\1", c("005", "0AB", "000", "0"))  

 ## [1] "5"  "AB" "0"  "0"
```

Here's an [R demo](https://ideone.com/MMh3F5).

Or expanding on *@akrun's answer*:

```r
sub("^$", "0", sub("^0+", "", c("005", "0AB", "000", "0")), perl = TRUE)
```